# Retrieve data for specific months

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

MySQL Query is like this

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(access_date) as date,
       DATE_FORMAT( access_date,  '%m/%Y' ) as month_date ,
       COUNT( log_id ) as total_count 
       FROM user_activity_log
 WHERE dam_id = (
                  SELECT dam_id
                         FROM dam_content_details 
                    WHERE content_type= '$content_type'
                 ) 
        AND access_date >= last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL ($month) MONTH)
        GROUP BY MONTH( access_date ) 
        ORDER BY access_date ASC
```

i will pass the numbers like 1,2,3.... then its giving value for that month.

The problem i faced is it retrieving the data per 30 days,60 days like that. I want if i will write $month = '1; then it should return the current month data & previous month data starting from day 1.

My sample output - $month = 2

```
date        month_date  total_count
---------  ------------ -----------
December    12/2013     4
January     01/2014     1
```

I want for december it should calculate from 12/01/2013. 1st December 2013. Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: What is the meaning of `01/2013`? Please explain..

Comment: Sorry just edited the question. Please refer that

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse No dude i dont have authorization to share sorry.

Comment: @RIADev - You don't have to use actual data for this - for most of these questions, anonymized/minimum data is fine.  Heck, from the columns we can see referenced in this query, the data in them is pretty meaningless on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove `=` from `>=`.

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(access_date) as date,
       DATE_FORMAT( access_date,  '%m/%Y' ) as month_date ,
       COUNT( log_id ) as total_count 
FROM user_activity_log
WHERE dam_id = (SELECT dam_id FROM dam_content_details WHERE content_type= '$content_type') AND 
      access_date > LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL (($month)+1) MONTH)
GROUP BY MONTH( access_date ) 
ORDER BY access_date ASC
```

Comment: @RIADev What is the problem you're facing??

Comment: See if i will pass 1 then its selecting current date to previous month in the interval of 30 days. But i want is current month starting from 1 to current date & similarly for previous month whole 30/31 days.

Comment: No same result...may be query need to be change ?